# How to add a header in top right corner of a textarea like in css tricks

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have made a textarea but I want tomake a header writing "**HTML**" in the top right corner in small letters like **css-tricks**.

My code:

```
<code><pre><textarea rows="16" cols="60" readonly style="resize:none; font-size: 18px;border:8px ridge #ff0000;">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang="en" dir="ltr"&gt;
   &lt;head&gt;
      &lt;meta charset="utf-8"&gt;
      &lt;title>Button Ripple Effect | #Programmer&lt;/title&gt;
   &lt;/head&gt;
   &lt;body&gt;
      &lt;div class="wrapper"&gt;
         &lt;div class="btns"&gt;
            &lt;a href="#"&gt;Button 1&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;a href="#"&gt;Button 2&lt;/a&gt;
         &lt;/div&gt;
      &lt;/div&gt;
   &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</textarea></pre></code>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need a bit of CSS. You may want to use a class selector instead, though.

```css
pre {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

pre::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    content: "HTML"
 }
```

```html
<pre><textarea rows="16" cols="60" readonly style="resize:none; font-size: 18px;border:8px ridge #ff0000;">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang="en" dir="ltr"&gt;
   &lt;head&gt;
      &lt;meta charset="utf-8"&gt;
      &lt;title>Button Ripple Effect | #Programmer&lt;/title&gt;
   &lt;/head&gt;
   &lt;body&gt;
      &lt;div class="wrapper"&gt;
         &lt;div class="btns"&gt;
            &lt;a href="#"&gt;Button 1&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;a href="#"&gt;Button 2&lt;/a&gt;
         &lt;/div&gt;
      &lt;/div&gt;
   &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</textarea></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy if you remove textarea element.
Because I think you don't need it.
To do that:

1. Add a `span` tag before any code.
2. Optional: Add (an `id` || a `class`)
3. Write Html in `span` tag.
4. In CSS set `code` tag's `position` to `relative`
5. In CSS set `span` tag's `position` to `absolute`
6. Style the span For example:

```css
background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
color: white;
padding: 6px 8px;
border: none;
outline: none;
/* Below gives it full round corners */
border-radius: 999px;
```

7. Then set it's position to right top corner:

```css
top: 5px;
right: 5px;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

8. Your Done!
   **Note:** If you are unfamiliar with some of the top propersties search css `that property`.
   For example `CSS outline`

---

The final:

```html
<pre><code>
<span class="tag">HTML</span>
<!-- Your codes -->
</code></pre>
```

And:

```css
pre > code {
  position: relative;
}
.tag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 8px;
  font: 300 10px sans-serif;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn a [CSS Grid Layout Module](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).

Here you have [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

In this use case, a CSS Grid is a bit like "Shooting birds with a cannon" but it is a great CSS tool that I am certain that you should learn and you will be grateful that you did.

It will eliminate such problems with positioning elements like in the GIF below:
[image]

I assume that You want to achieve a similar effect like in this snippet:

```css
header {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: end;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Button Ripple Effect | #Programmer</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <span class="logo">HTML</span>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="btns">
        <a href="#">Button 1</a>
        <a href="#">Button 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For future posts please add more info on what did you tried to achieve your goal and maybe add a sketch picture created eg. in Paint or handmade.